# How to print 10 numbers by adding each number by 3?

Tags: php

i am a newbie and i want to echo 10 numbers in a table of 10 rows by adding each number by 3

```
 <?php
$rows=10;
$cols=1;
echo "<table>";
for($r=1;$r<=$rows;$r  )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($c=1;$c<=$cols;$c  )
        echo '<td>'.$r.'</td>;
    echo '</tr>';
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I am getting the output as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

but I want the output in this way

```
1 
4
7
10
13
16
19
22
25
28
```

Comment: `echo '<td>'.(($r*3) - 2).'</td>;`

Comment: You have infinite loops, you're never incrementing `$r` or `$c`. Did you copy the code wrong?

Comment: Thanks alot..it worked

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `$skip` is the increment and `$totalNumbers` is the total numbers to show.

```
$skip = 3;
$totalNumbers = 10;
for($i=1;$i<=($skip*$totalNumbers);$i+=$skip) echo $i . " ";
```

Output:

```
1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close :) The second for cycle wasn't necessary.

```
<?php

$rows=10;
$cols=1;
echo "<table>";
$value = 1;
for($r=1;$r<=$rows;$r++)
{

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $value += 3;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

try use this

```
$rows=10;
$cols=1;
echo $cols.' </br>';
for ($i=1;$i<$rows;$i++){
  $cols=$cols+3;
  echo $cols.' </br> ';
}
```